# Create a hidden Menu similar to the FB and Gmail iPhone app, on button click, the page slides half way to reveal the menu

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to create a Menu similar to the FB and Gmail iPhone app. In these apps, the main menu is hidden by default. When a user clicks a button (at the top left), the main page slides to the right half way to reveal the menu options.

I was wondering, if that option was possible in Xcode or is it something that is totally customized?

Can someone please shed some light on this topic?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native UIKit component that does this, but several third-parties components that implement this style of navigation have been created.

[Here's one, for example](https://github.com/newmarcel/MKDSlideViewController)